# Using bootstrap fileinput with .NET core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, bootstrap-file-input

I'm trying to use Krajee's Bootstrap Fileinput (http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input) and having some problems.

The input field is in a form which has a submit button

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-action="CreeAnnonce" asp-controller="Vendeur">
```

My problem is when I upload files with the Fileinput, it runs the action method CreeAnnonce as if I click on the submit button of the form

[image]

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CreeAnnonce(Annonce annonce, IFormFile[] photo)
    {
        ...
```

I would like to run another action method (in AJAX) when I click on "upload" but I don't know how.

Please help me

Comment: you need more details of your code.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to run another action method (in AJAX) when I click on "upload" but I don't know how.

You can try to add `onsubmit` to form,and call ajax with `onsubmit`:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return handleClick()">
    <input id="input-b2" name="input-b2" type="file" class="file" data-show-preview="false">
</form>
```

js:

```
function handleClick() {
            alert("handleClick");
        }
```

result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need this code on Upload.cshtml Section:

```html
<link href="~/lib/fileUpload/css/fileinput.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/lib/fileUpload/themes/explorer-fas/theme.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="~/lib/fileUpload/js/plugins/piexif.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/lib/fileUpload/js/plugins/sortable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/lib/fileUpload/js/fileinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/lib/fileUpload/js/locales/fr.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/lib/fileUpload/js/locales/es.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/lib/fileUpload/themes/fas/theme.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/lib/fileUpload/themes/explorer-fas/theme.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<form asp-action="Upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="hidden" value="8" id="GalleryID" name="GalleryID" />
            <div class="file-loading">
                <input id="kv-explorer" name="files" type="file" multiple>
            </div>
        </form>
        
        <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#kv-explorer").fileinput({
            //'theme': 'fas',
            'theme': 'explorer-fas',
            overwriteInitial: false,
            initialPreviewAsData: true,
            //uploadUrl: "/Upload",
            uploadAsync: false,
            maxFileCount: 5,
            //minFileCount: 2,

            maxFileSize: 80000,
            maxFilesNum: 10,

            allowedFileExtensions: ['jpg', 'png', 'gif'],
            //allowedFileTypes: ['image', 'video', 'flash'],

            //showUpload: false,
            //showRemove: false,
            //showPreview: false,
            //initialPreview: [
            //    "http://lorempixel.com/1920/1080/nature/1",
            //    "http://lorempixel.com/1920/1080/nature/2",
            //    "http://lorempixel.com/1920/1080/nature/3"
            //],
            //initialPreviewConfig: [
            //    {caption: "nature-1.jpg", size: 329892, width: "120px", url: "{$url}", key: 1},
            //    {caption: "nature-2.jpg", size: 872378, width: "120px", url: "{$url}", key: 2},
            //    {caption: "nature-3.jpg", size: 632762, width: "120px", url: "{$url}", key: 3}
            //]

            //uploadExtraData: {
            //    img_key: "1000",
            //    img_keywords: "happy, places",
            //}
            uploadExtraData: function () {
                return {
                    GalleryID: $("#GalleryID").val(),
                };
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

You need to put all Css and js files in the first of the **Upload.cshtml** code. Then you need to set some initializer for it(script at the end of Upload.cshtml).

For the controller section, I suggest you use **IFormFile**.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(IEnumerable<IFormFile> files, string GalleryID /*same name with input name*/)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (var item in files)
            {
                var UploadsRootFolder = Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, "GalleryFiles");
                if (!Directory.Exists(UploadsRootFolder))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(UploadsRootFolder);
                }
                if (item != null)
                {
                    string FileExtension = Path.GetExtension(item.FileName);
                    string NewFileName = string.Concat(Guid.NewGuid(), FileExtension);
                    string path = Path.Combine(UploadsRootFolder, NewFileName);

                    using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        await item.CopyToAsync(stream);
                    }
                    CompressImage(NewFileName);
                }
            }
            
            return new JsonResult("success");
        }
        catch
        {
            return new EmptyResult();
        }
        
    }
```

This controller is for multiple files.
If you want **Ajax Upload** you can use these codes in the script initializer(At the in the of Upload.cshtml).

```
uploadUrl: "/Upload",
//uploadAsync: false,
```

Use [Route("Upload")] for your **Upload** controller(uploadUrl in above and in **Route["Upload"]** must have same name)